# Convert SQL query to hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to create a hibernate query that can join parent and child table. The relationship between parent and child is 1-to-many. I only need to retrieve the child with the largest id. Using native SQL, I can do the following:

```
select *
from parent p, child c
where p.id=c.parent_id and c.id = 
(
      select max(id) 
      from child where parent_id=p.id
);
```

I am not very familiar with HQL. Can someone help me translate it to HQL?

Thanks!

Comment: should be trivial. For hql its just the class names instead of tables. and select * is implied, ie select * from mytable m where m.field = value=> from myTableObject m where m.field = value. Try someting like this if it gives some errors post again.

Comment: see if this gets you started: http://kristantohans.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/basic-introduction-of-objectrelational-mapping-and-hql/